# React Native load image ficker on the first

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

when I first enter a scene in a react native project with a iPhone 4S, load some local image will have a delay whenever the image's size is 10KB or 100KB, or other size. I was doubt that what's the problem with it. Anyone know about it? And what should I do to fix it?

Comment: Is the image local or loaded on the network?

Comment: local image @NaderDabit